# ListView Custom Draw - Multi-colored text inside individual cell?

Tags: winapi, listview, colors, custom-draw

As far as I know you can use Custom Draw in a list-view to paint individual cells the way you want using CDDS_SUBITEM.

However, I would like to have multi-colored text **within a cell**. That is, I would like to, for example, set a cell's text to: "this program is called the [start red text]Red Program[end red text]" - is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in your `NMCUSTOMDRAW` structure you get an HDC.  You will need to call [DrawText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162498%28VS.85%29.aspx) multiple times.  You may be able to just call [SetTextColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145093%28VS.85%29.aspx) to do that, or you may have to call [SelectObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162957%28VS.85%29.aspx) and select in your own custom [Pen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162786%28VS.85%29.aspx) to change the color...  yay GDI.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How would I go about figuring out which section of the rectangle I'm given to draw in corresponds to each colored token?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You break your string into the various colors, then use DrawText (and maybe MeasureText) to figure out the rect for each one.

Comment: I'll need to call DrawText to draw each individual token, and I'll need to know the rect for each one -- but I only get one HDC/rect from the notification. How do I "figure out the rect" using DrawText? Doesn't it just take in a rect as input? And what is MeasureText?

Comment: Oh yeah, use use DrawText() to get the size your text will take (note the rect param is in/out).  NMCUSTOMDRAW has a rect member.  Did you try that guy?  Once you have the bounding rect and the size your text will take, it's just simple 2D geometry.

Comment: Oh yeah, the `NMLVCUSTOMDRAW` struct you get has a rectangle that specifies the rect the text should be drawn in.  Even better, you don't have to figure out the margins.

Comment: Okay, I think I've just about got it. I'm having a few minor issues with spacing but besides that, it's working out great. Thanks mate!

Comment: Cool.  Yeah, GDI is a pain for stuff like this.  You see why they were so keen to build WFP and Silverlight.  :)